# Unterschied zwischen «mahnen» und «ermahnen»

Tags: meaning, difference

Wie unterscheiden sich die Begriffe *mahnen* und *Mahnung* von *ermahnen* und *Ermahnung*?

Zum Beispiel: Wenn ich jemanden auffordere eine Schuld zu bezahlen, *mahne* ich ihn dann oder *ermahne* ich ihn? Sind beide Begriffe hier austauschbar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Obwohl beide Begriffe recht ähnlich bzw. synonym sind, ist der Kontext, in denen sie verwendet werden, unterschiedlich. Während *ermahnen* und *Ermahnung* in der Regel auf direkte, zwischenmenschliche Gespräche Bezug nimmt, wird *mahnen* und *Mahnung* vor allem im postalischen Schriftverkehr verwendet.

Beispiele:

> - Die Lehrerin ermahnte den Schüler, seinen Sitznachbarn nicht zu
>   hänseln.
> - Das Kind erhielt eine Ermahnung durch seine Mutter.

---

> - Wir haben heute eine Mahnung an den Kunden ausgesandt, mit der Aufforderung, den fehlenden
>   Betrag schnellstmöglich zu begleichen.

Answer (score 6):

Eine Ermahnung ist immer direkt an jemanden gerichtet.

Mahnen kann entweder eine förmliche Ermanung sein, oder generell gerichtet:

> Er *mahnte*, dass die Meeresspiegel steigen würden, wenn der CO2-Ausstoß
>   nicht reduziert würde.

Hier kann *ermahnen* nicht verwendet werden, da niemand direkt angesprochen wird.

Answer (score 0):

Habe mal etwas recherchiert und laut Duden sind es keine nennenswerten Unterschiede, zumal "ermahnen" als mögliches Synonym für "mahnen" angegeben wird.

http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/mahnen
http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ermahnen

Beides bedeutet die Hinweisung auf ein bestimmtes Verhalten, das geboten erscheint oder sogar eine Pflicht ist.

Answer (score 0):

Ich assoziiere mit *mahnen* – insbesondere im Schriftverkehr – automatisch die *Mahngebühr*. Das heißt, ich würde jemanden so lange *ermahnen*, bis mir klar wird, dass das nichts geholfen hat, und eine *Mahnung* mit Gebühr fällig wird.